# how to rerun switch case loop after some cases have already run

Tags: java, switch-statement

In this class of Bank ,there are basic functions of Bank , however the real problem is in the switch case loop.

```
class Bank{ 
    private int Balance;
    private int Withdrawal;
    private int Deposit;
    private int AccountNumber;  

void Transaction(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the account number to whose account you                 want 
to transfer money");
    AccountNumber = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your current Balance");
    Balance= input.nextInt();

    }
void Display(){
    System.out.println("Account number "+AccountNumber);
    System.out.println("Balance is "+ Balance);
    }
void deposit(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the amount to deposit");
    int n =input.nextInt();
    Balance+=n;
}
void withdraw(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the amount to withdraw");
    int n =input.nextInt();
try {
    if(n>Balance)
     throw new Exception("The balance you have is insufficient");
  }
 catch(Exception e){

System.out.println(e);
 }
   }//void
```

I am trying to rerun the switch case loop, after inputing one value , i want it to ask user again all the options, i tried to use continue statement , but it shows error of continue outside the loop.Please help

```
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{

    Bank b1=new Bank();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number corrosponding to your option ");
    System.out.println("1 Set ");
    System.out.println("2 Display ");
    System.out.println("3 Deposit");
    System.out.println("4 Withdraw");
    System.out.println("5 Exit");

    int num=input.nextInt();
    switch(num){
         case 1:
                b1.Transaction();
                //int c =input.nextInt();
                //wants user to input value again so switch loop works 
                 //again

                break;  
         case 2:
                b1.Display();
                break;
         case 3:
                b1.deposit();
                break;
         case 4:
                b1.withdraw();
                break;
         case 5:
            return;

        }

    }//psvm
 }
```

Comment: the programming language is java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could surround the switch in a

```
do{
 int num=input.nextInt();
  switch(num){
         case 1:
                break;  
         case 2:
                break;
         case 3:
                break;
         case 4:
                break;
         case 5:
            return;
        }
}while(num!=some_value_to_exit_switch);
    }
 }
```

Comment: sorry for late  reply ..thanks , this totally worked

Answer (score 0):

I'd place the `switch` content in a `while` loop with a boolean flag, then it will re-run until you are satisfied with the input~